# How to mock/double the following method in my rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method that does roughly the following:

```
def some_method(....)

  user = User.where("....").first

  if !user.nil?

     if ..
         user.delete
     elsif
         user.update_attributes(...)

  else
     new_user = User.new(...)
     new_user.save!
  end

end
```

There is allot of branching so I will have to create a few tests for each case.

How can I create mock objects to make sure specific methods are called?

How can I differentiate between the various objects in my test?

e.g.

```
user = User.where("....")
```

and

```
new_user = User.new("...")
new_user.save!
```

I have to somehow test for a call to where, and return sometimes nil and sometimes a user object.  And I have to test if save! is called and returns true.
And also test for deletes on a specific object (the one from the where clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stub class methods with RSpec, e.g.

```
User.should_receive(:where).and_return([])
```

Comment: It's failing b/c of the call to .first, how can I test for this case?  User.where("...").first

Comment: User.should_receive(:where).and_return([double('user')])

Comment: but isnt' it expecting a call to .first?

Comment: You could write User.stub_chain(:where, :first).and_return(nil) but the result is the same.